# FFmpeg. Combine drawtext, fade and afade filters with filter_complex

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, console, video-editing

I have these two codes that work fine, separately

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4  -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=Lato-Light.ttf:text='TEXT':fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:alpha='if(lt(t,2),0,if(lt(t,4),(t-2)/2,if(lt(t,11),1,if(lt(t,13),(2-(t-11))/2,0))))':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-20,pad=width=ceil(iw/2)*2:height=ceil(ih/2)*2" out.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=type=in:duration=2,fade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=16[v];[0:a]afade=type=in:duration=2,afade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=16[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  out.mp4
```

Can you tell me how I can combine both in a single command? I have tried everything and I cannot find any tutorial or example that could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=Lato-Light.ttf:text='TEXT':fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:alpha='if(lt(t,2),0,if(lt(t,4),(t-2)/2,if(lt(t,11),1,if(lt(t,13),(2-(t-11))/2,0))))':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-20,pad=width=ceil(iw/2)*2:height=ceil(ih/2)*2,fade=type=in:duration=2,fade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=16;afade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=16" out.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation: Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).